# Can I duplicate a row with a few different columns? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need your help What I am looking for is to obtain the table below starting from the table above. I have tried various things and they have not worked.

```
Date   ID     Typol   Facial#1   Facial#2

abril  426     COR      1000        500
```

```
Date   ID     Typol   Facial

abril  426     COR      1000  
abril  426     LAR      500
```

If Typol is COR, use Facial #1 value y duplicate the row with de column Typol different (a opositive value) and de Facial column with de Facial #2

Comment: Where did you get the value of `LAR` for the second row?

Comment: is the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward create 2 df each with one Facial column and then concat.

Code:

```
df1 = df[['Date','ID','Typol','Facial#1']]
df1.rename(columns = {"Facial#1": "Facial"}, inplace = True)

df2 = df[['Date','ID','Typol','Facial#2']]
df2.rename(columns = {"Facial#2": "Facial"}, inplace = True)

df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Comment: It also works if it is with conditions? For example, what Facial # 2 is when Typol is FRW otherwise put Facial # 1

Comment: It is for many rows of the initial data frame. Those of the same date must be followed

Answer (score 0):

## Version 2:

**duplicate rows, move Facial#2 to Facial#1, also consider Typol value**

```
c = ['Date','ID','Typol','Facial#1','Facial#2']
d = [['abril',426,'COR',1000,500],
     ['test1',537,'LAR',1500,750]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

df['Typol_X'] = df['Typol']
df.loc[(df['Typol'] == 'COR'), 'Typol_X'] = 'LAR'
df.loc[(df['Typol'] == 'LAR') & (df['Typol_X'] == 'LAR'), 'Typol_X'] = 'COR'

print (df)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
df.iloc[1::2,3] = df.iloc[::2,4]
df.iloc[1::2,2] = df.iloc[::2,5]
df.drop(['Facial#2','Typol_X'], axis=1,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

**Original dataframe:**

```
    Date   ID Typol  Facial#1  Facial#2 Typol_X
0  abril  426   COR      1000       500     LAR
1  test1  537   LAR      1500       750     COR
```

**Updated dataframe:**

```
    Date   ID Typol  Facial#1
0  abril  426   COR      1000
1  abril  426   LAR       500
2  test1  537   LAR      1500
3  test1  537   COR       750
```

## Version 1:

**duplicate rows, move Facial#2 to Facial#1**

An alternate way to do this will be as follows:

```
c = ['Date','ID','Typol','Facial#1','Facial#2']
d = [['abril',426,'COR',1000,500],
     ['test1',537,'DPS',1500,750]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
df.iloc[1::2,3] = df.iloc[::2,4]
df.drop(['Facial#2'], axis=1,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

**Original dataframe:**

```
    Date   ID Typol  Facial#1  Facial#2
0  abril  426   COR      1000       500
1  test1  537   DPS      1500       750
```

**Updated dataframe:**

```
    Date   ID Typol  Facial#1
0  abril  426   COR      1000
1  abril  426   COR       500
2  test1  537   DPS      1500
3  test1  537   DPS       750
```

Comment: But in your code the duplicate row has the same value in Typol. I need it to have a different value, like its opposite (white / black)

Comment: See if the updated answer addresses your additional ask.